unable to stub the class when writing test case for a generic function with Cuckoo
I am writing test cases for a generic method. Following is the function:
    public protocol NetworkManager {
        func execute<R: NetworkRequest, T: Decodable>(
            with request: R,
            parameters: [NetworkParameter]?
        ) async throws -> T
    }
struct PARRequest: NetworkRequest {
  var baseURL: String?
  typealias Response = AuthorizationResponseDTO

  var method: NetworkMethod { .GET }
  var additionalHeaders: [String: String] {[:]}
  var path: String = ""
  
  var body: Data? = nil
    
  let request: AuthorizationRequestDTO?
    
    init(request: AuthorizationRequestDTO? = nil, baseURL: String? = nil) {
        self.request = request
        self.baseURL = baseURL
    }
}

Following is my failure test case:
func testExecutePARRefreshURL_ThrowsError() async {
    // Arrange
    let testURL = "https://test.com"
    let expectedResponse = AuthorizationResponseDTO(authorizationCode: "authorisation_code", serverState: "state", dpopNonce: "dpop_nonce")
    let expectedError = NSError(domain: "TestErrorDomain", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    let request = PARRequest(baseURL: testURL) // create the request

    stub(mockNetworkManager) { stub in
        when(stub.execute(with: any(PARRequest.self), parameters: any())).thenThrow(expectedError)
    }

    do {
        _ = try await sut.executePARRefreshURL(with: testURL)
        XCTFail("Expected error but got success")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        XCTAssertEqual(error.domain, expectedError.domain)
    }

    verify(mockNetworkManager).execute(with: request, parameters: nil)
}

I am getting following error when setting stub:

Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred


I have no idea what mocking library you are using but to me it looks like you need to  define what the function returns.
